# ESP8266 connected to a HIGH pin and DPDT only works sometimes. Works everytime if connected to 3V3 pin

Tags: esp8266, switch

I have a Wemos D1 Mini hooked up to a DS2Y-S-DC3V DPDT switch. 
When I have the coil ends are hooked up to a pin (D2) and ground, it will click when I set the pin HIGH. It should click again when it goes low, and then again with high, etc. But after while, it stops responding. Measuring the voltage while hooked up to the DPDT is 1.7 V.  When disconnected from the DPDT, the D2 pin and Ground voltage is as expected, 3.3V.
However, if I connect the DPDT terminals to the ESP's 3V3 pin and G, it works all day as many times as I wish. 
I have multiple DPDTs. And two of the 6 don't work as expected. Why does it work when I directly hook it up to 3v terminal but not a HIGH pin? Shouldn't both be 3v?

Any ideas?

Comment: please add a schematic diagram of the connections ... it is unclear what is happening when you press the switch

Comment: you damage the pin. it can't supply the current for the coil